# Resizing window by dragging it to the edge - resize by more than 50%

Tags: 16.04, compiz, window

Is there any way to change the default width when resizing window by dragging it to the edge? I would like to have something like:
- when i drag to the left edge, window will resize to 60% of the current screen width
- when i drag to the right edge, window will resize to 40% of the current screen width

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity.

Comment: Please add the used desktop (probably Unity) as this probably something very different across different desktops.

Comment: you are right, I am using Unity, thanks for a good catch :)

Comment: How about keyboard shortcuts for the specific width percentage ? This can be done fairly easy with a script bound to a shortcut

Comment: There is an option in compiz to choose that pressing `ctrl + alt + NUM_RIGHT` or `NUM_LEFT` multiple times will cause window to resize to 75%, 50%, 33% and 25% i think. It's nice, but still i would like to be able to just drag my window to the left and right and have it resized in 60-40 proportion.